# wxPython Pheonix TextCtrl Widget not changing size

Tags: python, wxpython

Recently did an upgrade to my debian distribution to debian jesse

I notice my GUI program which I wrote in wxpython 2.8 was not displaying propery in wxpython3.0

Specifically, the text control box and button was not the same size. To add to this, I attempt to change the size of the mentioned widgets but it remained. the same.

Just to check if I am sane

I created two input box in a frame as follows:

```
class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self,title, pos, size):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1, title, pos, size)
        self.input_box_search=wx.TextCtrl(self,-1,pos=(90,13),size=(400,80),style=wx.BORDER_NONE)
        self.input_box_search1=wx.TextCtrl(self,-1,pos=(90,103),size=(400,40),style=wx.BORDER_NONE)
```

The two TextCtrl boxes had the same size!
the picture below shows how two textctrl boxes of different size are displayed in wxpython3.0

[image]
Note: using wxpython2.8, each box size displayed correctly.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I used python2.7 to run my Application

Comment: Are you using sizers? A complete, small, runnable example would be good so we could test it too.

Comment: Works for me using wxPython Phoenix on Windows 8.1.  What exact wxPython version are you using?  If classic then you should try with 3.0.2.

Comment: I am using No box sizers..the window frame is fixed with widgets have fixed position.....I am using wxpython3.0.1.1.....when i execute "wx.version()" in python2.7 shell i got 
"wx.version()
'3.0.1.1 gtk2 (classic)'"

Comment: @Xorg you should try it with 3.0.2.

Comment: last night i compiled wxpython 3.0.2 and same results...I notice when i put the widgets in a boxsizer,the sizes were correctly shown...without no boxsizers, i get the same results...I really want to use the html2 module to do some styling effects...hmm....thank u

Comment: I found a workaround to my solution....i place the textctrl box in a box sizer and place the boxsizer in a small panel and everything was perfect!